# MINIFs Due Date

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image: example of Sample Data]

Hi all,

I am trying to get my Due Date formula based and I had it fine but want to build on this so that if something is a Priority ticket, the Due Date is either set for the end of the month (Based on Column N) or the Turnaround Times [whichever comes first].

Could someone help me work this out and also if someone can advise why it comes up as FALSE for EOMONTH? I can use that formula out of the table and it works so not sure why that is coming up FALSE

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Shea

Comment: Simply post few sample data and then show your desired output. Then explain logic.

Comment: Does the image not open? :/

Comment: You need formula for only this one row data?

Comment: Post data and formulas as text which can by copy/pasted. See [why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=For%20larger%20code%20snippets%2C%20you,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't give us the formula (only an image of it), let me give you a way to solve such a problem in a general way, using formula auditing evaluation. This can be found in the "Formulas" ribbon, "Formula auditing" menu, "Evaluate Formula" button.

When you start this, you'll see a text window, underlining the variable/calculation which will be calculated next (when you choose "Evaluate"), this will allow you to see unexpected results, on which you can decide to correct your formula, as in the following screenshot:

[image]